# Node.js application stopping after running a loop for a while

Tags: javascript, node.js, plotly

I am trying to run some code to update a plotly graph every minute, but when I run it using Node.js it stops after a small amount of time and does not update my account. Here is my code (not including my plotly account init, which has my plotly API key)

```
let n = 0
let start = Date.now()
let timer = Date.now() - timestart
var timestart = Date.now()

let arr = [1, 5, 4, 3, 6]
let ar = [2, 2, 3, 5, 7]
let data = [{
    x: arr,
    y: ar,
    type: 'line'
}]
let layout = {
    fileopt: "overwrite",
    filename: "prime size overtime"
}


function run() {
    console.log('test')
    while (timer < 60000) {
        n += 1
        console.log(n)
        timer = Date.now() - timestart
        ar.push(n)
        arr.push(Date.now() - start)
        data = [{
            x: arr,
            y: ar,
            type: 'line'
        }]
    }
    send()
}

function send() {
    plotly.plot(data, layout, function(err, msg) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(msg);
    });
    run()
}
run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it will stop.

You have two methods here, `send()` and `run()`.

At first, the `run()` method is invoked, and then the `run()` method invokes the `send()` method. At the end of the `send()` method, the `run()` method is invoked again.

It is working like:

```
run() -> send() -> run() -> send() ......
```

So, your application eventually reached the maximum stack size and stopped.

Comment: this is unfortunate because for some reason plotly will not update its server in a infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

Set a timeout for 60 seconds to invoke `run` again:

```
function send() {
    plotly.plot(data, layout, function(err, msg) {
        // ...
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
       run()
    }, 60e3)
}
```